# linking two table in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have two tables which are linked via a hasMany relationship. One is for members.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Member extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email'];

    public function schools()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(School::class);
    }
}
```

The other one is for schools.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class School extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['school'];

    public function member()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Member::class);
    }
}
```

I want to submit one form that the user fills in but unfortunately, I get the following error.

```
 General error: 1364 Field 'member_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `schools` (`school`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Eton, 2017-05-26 13:28:50, 2017-05-26 13:28:50))
```

Comment: Is it many to many relationship? If the member has only one School then the member `belongsTo` the school. Otherwise there is a `belongsToMany` relationship too. Please show the schema of tables.

Comment: You have set many to many relationships, so first make sure you have pivot table set correctly. As per the error in query, I'm guessing that you don't have that table called member_school in the database

Comment: here are the schema tables.

Comment: `public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('members', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('name');

            $table->string('email');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
`

Comment: and for the school.

Comment: `public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('schools', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('member_id');

            $table->string('school');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }`

Comment: Could this be how I have setup the form?